# What's the opposite of query builder's with()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

My schema has it that table `A` has one `B` which in turn has one `C`.

When I fetch all `A`, I can see in my returned data instead of a reference to `B`; I just get it's id. This is what I want.

When I fetch `A->with('B')` I get `A` and object references all the way up to `C`! I just want `A` with `B` references, **not `C`** (which is a huge object, bloats my response, and contains sensitive data).

I want to do one of these two things. Either fetch `A` with `B` (no `C`), or find a way to traverse the paginated (using `LengthAwarePaginator`) object and strip the unwanted `C`s.

Are any of these options possible in Laravel? Is there any other approach to achieve the same thing?

Comment: As far as I know this is not the expected behavior. Can you share your `B` model?

Comment: @aleksejjj it's just an empty class with only the method describing the `hasOne()` relationship to C.

Comment: I just run same code and it works as expected for me. `dd(A::with('b')->get());` return A+B. `dd(A::with('b.c')->get());` return A+B+C

Comment: Here is all related files https://gist.github.com/aleksejjj/56171e45b21cbb50322765207d96d072

Comment: @aleksejjj Hmmm that's almost exactly what I'm doing. The only difference is that I'm using the length aware paginator via `paginate()`. What version of Laravel are you trying this on?

Comment: I'm using `5.3.16` but this is expected behavior for earlier versions too.. Are you getting same result without `paginate()`?

Comment: P.S. result with `paginate()` also correct for me.

Comment: @aleksejjj First of all, thanks for taking the time to try this out! I finally found the problem. In my app, `B` was not subclassing Eloquent directly and in this parent class it was appending an extra attribute. Inside the getter for this attribute there was a call to `C` so no matter what I did, `C` was always being required by this appended attribute! I've removed all that unneeded subclassing and it now works as expected. Many thanks!

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. In my app, B was not subclassing Eloquent directly and in this parent class it was appending an extra attribute. Inside the getter for this attribute there was a call to C so no matter what I did, C was always being required by this appended attribute! I've removed all that unneeded subclassing and it now works as expected.